# Counting Subqueries

Tags: sql

Say for example I have this table:

```
Items:
-------
id
title
price
```

And I wanted to create a query that created a new row that for each item, it would query another table that matched the id, with the id in the other table, set the row another row in the other table.

Comment: What are you asking? How to write an Update statement using `count` in a sub query?

Comment: edit your question with an example.

Comment: -1. i'm sorry; this question isn't very clearly stated

Comment: I will revise.  Something like... select id, title, count(select x from otherTable where otherTable.id = thisTable.id) as new_rows from thisTable 

I obviously know this doesn't work, however something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select
    ThisTable.id,
    title,
    price,
    other_count
from
(
    select
        id,
        count(*) as other_count
    from OtherTable
    group by id
) OtherTableCount
    inner join ThisTable
        on ThisTable.id = OtherTable.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want something like "select id, title, count(select x from otherTable where otherTable.id = thisTable.id) as new_rows from thisTable"

I think you need a grouped join like

```
select
    id,
    title,
    count(*)
from
    thisTable,
    otherTable
where
    (otherTable.foreignRefKey = thisTable.id)
group by
    id,
    title
```

That would do it, I think.  Use outer joins if otherTable can have no records referencing thisTable